# how to copy between two host machine and windows server client using ansible faster?

Tags: linux, windows, ansible

My aim is to copy from a machine A(ubuntu) to remote server B(windows2012 server) using ansible copy command. I can ping the windows server machine and can even copy a small folder from ubunto to server but when the folder size becomes big it takes so so long to get copied and sometimes not get copied . I am using as follows:

```
 -name:copy file
  win_copy:
    src: '/service/test.zip'
    dest:'D:/test/test.zip'
```

test.zip folder is around 300 MB. So, win_copy is not solving my purpose. Could you suggest what can be good option in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem and just wrote a powershell script to download the file directly to a known location on the target.  Write a powershell script to [download the file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx).  I would deploy the script to the target using [win_copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_copy_module.html) or [win_template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_template_module.html) (if you need to do substitutions) and then call it using [win_command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_command_module.html).